Radzen Blazor sidebar expanded doesn't work
I'm using Radzen layout component for my Blazor app MainLayout
but the sidebar-expanded doesn't work as it is in the documentation. If I click the toggle, the sidebar wont collapsed nor expanded.
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using Radzen
@using Radzen.Blazor
<RadzenComponents @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

<RadzenLayout>
    <RadzenHeader>
        <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center" Gap="0">
            <RadzenSidebarToggle Click="@ToggleSidebar" />
            <RadzenLabel Text="Header" />
        </RadzenStack>
    </RadzenHeader>
    <RadzenSidebar Responsive="false" Style="width: max-content">
        <RadzenPanelMenu DisplayStyle="@(sidebarExpanded ? MenuItemDisplayStyle.IconAndText : MenuItemDisplayStyle.Icon)" ShowArrow="false">
            <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Overview" Icon="home" Path="/" />
            <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Dashboard" Icon="dashboard" Path="counter" />
            <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="UI Fundamentals" Icon="auto_awesome">
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Themes" Icon="color_lens" />
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Colors" Icon="invert_colors" />
            </RadzenPanelMenuItem>
        </RadzenPanelMenu>
    </RadzenSidebar>
    
    <div class="rz-p-4">
        @Body
    </div>
    <RadzenFooter>
        Footer
    </RadzenFooter>
</RadzenLayout>

@code {
    bool sidebarExpanded = true;

    void ToggleSidebar()
    {
        sidebarExpanded = !sidebarExpanded;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

I'm using .Net 8 server-side render mode and I've made sure that the installation for the Radzen is correct, because it works just fine with the other Radzen component but the sidebar. I don't know what else's wrong.

Find your App.razor and change Routes like below, it will work.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorApp.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <RadzenTheme Theme="material" @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer"/>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js?v=@(typeof(Radzen.Colors).Assembly.GetName().Version)"></script>
</body>

</html>


It was the <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer"/> line that fixed my issue after an hour of trying to resolve it. Thank you.
